# Screen keeps freezing but cursor can still move.

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Any idea how I would figure out what is causing this problem? I downloaded psensor to see if anything is overheating but that doesn't seem to be the cause...I've been having to restart the computer a few times a day and when I tried playing a DVD with VLC it kept happening even more often.

I'm running 18.04.1 and I'm using the proprietary driver for my graphics card

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a hardware problem to me. I'd first try reseating your video card. If you have onboard graphics or another graphics card, it might be worth trying them to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into console mode with `ctrl+alt+f1` and check the logs in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`. These files could give you an idea of what is going wrong.

You could try `tail -100 <FILENAME>`, to get the last 100 lines of the file.

Maybe you don't have to restart your computer, just restarting the desktop service will be enough (given that your cursor is still working, it is not a total freeze of the system)